# What is the difference between "in", "aus" and "bei" with “arbeiten”?

Tags: english-to-german, verb, preposition

What is the difference between *arbeiten in*, *… aus* and *… bei*?
Even if it seems that the second one means ‘from’ and the first one ‘at’ (from [wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/ende/I%20work%20at%20the%20university.)), when I wrote:

“Ich arbeite in der Uni.”

“Ich arbeite aus <del>die</del> der Uni.”

“Ich arbeite bei der Uni.”

It seems to be the same for it according to the messy [translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/#de/en/Ich%20arbeite%20an%20der%20Universit%C3%A4t.%0AIch%20arbeite%20bei%20der%20Universit%C3%A4t.%0AIch%20arbeite%20f%C3%BCr%20die%20Universit%C3%A4t.%0AIch%20arbeite%20mit%20der%20Universit%C3%A4t.%0AIch%20arbeite%20wegen%20der%20Universit%C3%A4t.%0AIch%20arbeite%20dank%20der%20Universit%C3%A4t.%0AIch%20arbeite%20aus%20der%20Universit%C3%A4t%20heraus.) and [languagetool.org](http://languagetool.org).

Comment: Why do you think that these two mean they same? The second is just wrong.

Comment: translate.google and languagetool.org told me...

Comment: Google gets most related simple sentences absolutely right. What *exactly* did you try to translate and where *exactly* did the translators fail you? I put some links into the question to show what I think you might have been doing – but I can’t make sense out of it, because I see no problem (except with wordreference.com maybe).

Comment: Of course, automatic translation is **garbage in — something out**.

Comment: Ich arbeite in Berlin aus Spaß an der Freude bei der Humbold-Uni.

Comment: Ich arbeite von Zuhause (aus)  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*in der Uni - would mean inside (location). 

aus die Uni - is incorrect. 

bei der Uni - doesn't sound natural.*

I work at the University. (Correct) 
Ich arbeite an der Uni.

You would use bei if you are talking about a company.
Ich arbeite bei einer Firma.

Comment: _Ich arbeite bei **einer** Firma._

Comment: Welcome to the German Language StackExchange. If you want, you can take the [tour], or take a look at the [help]. Have a nice day!

Comment: *Bei der Uni* is perfectly fine, to express the fact, that your office is near the university, but one does not work for the university itself.